# How to catch and ignore ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique exception in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rescue

I had ruby script job running daily for loading data from one table to another until there were duplicate key records found in the source table since that table had no constraints. My target table rejected those records cuz the target table had primary key constraints on columns (head_date, center_id, site_url). My program just  halted and showed the error below on the command line. :-(

```
in `async_exec': PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "tst_data_pkey" (ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique)
```

I can expect the source table to have other nasty records like this. How can I continue processing and move on to the next record after catching this active record exception?

Below is the code for my updates/inserts:

```
class SiteSection < ActiveRecord::Base

  SiteSection.establish_connection(
        :adapter  => 'postgresql',
        :host     => 'hoster-of-hosts.com',
        :database => 'super-inven',
        :username => 'user',
        :password => 'pass'
                      )
  self.table_name = 'master.target_tbl'  # << insert into this table
end

conn.query("select * from source_tbl") do |row|
  siteData = SiteSection.find_or_initialize_by_head_date_and_center_id_and_site_url(row[:date_c], row[:com_id], row[:site_link])

  siteData[:head_date]      = row[:date_c]
  siteData[:center_id]     = row[:com_id]
  siteData[:site_url]          = row[:site_link].nil? ? 'unknown' : row[:site_link]
  siteData[:people_cnt]      = row[:persons].nil? ? 0 : row[:persons]
  siteData[:ips]     = row[:ip_adds].nil? ? 0 : row[:ip_adds]

  siteData.save
i = i+1
puts "finished: #{i}" if i % 10000 == 0
end
conn.close
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a

```
begin

rescue => e

end
```

like this:

```
class SiteSection < ActiveRecord::Base

  SiteSection.establish_connection(
        :adapter  => 'postgresql',
        :host     => 'hoster-of-hosts.com',
        :database => 'super-inven',
        :username => 'user',
        :password => 'pass'
                      )
  self.table_name = 'master.target_tbl'  # << insert into this table
end

conn.query("select * from source_tbl") do |row|
  siteData = SiteSection.find_or_initialize_by_head_date_and_center_id_and_site_url(row[:date_c], row[:com_id], row[:site_link])

  siteData[:head_date]      = row[:date_c]
  siteData[:center_id]     = row[:com_id]
  siteData[:site_url]          = row[:site_link].nil? ? 'unknown' : row[:site_link]
  siteData[:people_cnt]      = row[:persons].nil? ? 0 : row[:persons]
  siteData[:ips]     = row[:ip_adds].nil? ? 0 : row[:ip_adds]

  begin
    siteData.save
  rescue => e
    puts e.message
    puts "Error happened but I'll just keep chuggin along"
  end
i = i+1
puts "finished: #{i}" if i % 10000 == 0
end
conn.close
```

The `rescue => e` is expecting to catch an error. It will swallow that error by not letting it bubble up. Your code will continue to run without the exception crashing it.

Comment: You sure it exception needs to surround the self.table_name = 'master.target_tbl'? Why is that? I thought it should surround the part where it is actually inserting or siteData.save command. Please let me know the logic so that I can better understand.. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, it would get raised on the `save`. Fixed

Answer (score -1):

If you have unique key you should use it - something like this:

```
i = 0
puts 'loading records'
conn.query("select * from source_tbl") do |row|
  rec = SiteSection.where(
    :head_date => row[:date_c],
    :center_id => row[:com_id],
    :site_url => (row[:site_link] || 'unknown')
  ).first_or_initialize

  rec.people_cnt = (row[:persons] || 0)
  rec.ips => (row[:ip_adds] || 0)

  rec.save!

  i += 1
  print '.' if i % 10000 == 0
end
puts "done\ntotal records: #{i}"
```

This way you will save a record (new) or update ones (if found). No `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` should be here if you didn't change you pkey!

Comment: BTW - if you still have an error you can user `begin ... rescue => e ... end` block. But you should not have an error here ;)